# Tkinter: Problem when update values in textboxes. Any errors, but the database doesn't update

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I have some textboxes (`textbox1`, `textbox2`) that I will need to continuously update their value. I have already created a database with values in it. I would like that when I write a value in the two textboxes, the corresponding value in the database is subsequently updated. Considering that I will be inserting many textboxes, I would like each textbox to automatically correspond to its rows in the database

I don't get any errors, but the database doesn't update

Here is the database:

```
CREATE TABLE "valuedb" (
"id" INTEGER,
"all_value" INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

Python code is:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("130x100")

#Textbox
textbox1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=7)
textbox1.place(x=1, y=1)

textbox2 = ttk.Entry(root, width=7)
textbox2.place(x=1, y=30)


#Save
def save():
    con = sqlite3.connect("/home/MyPc/Destktop/my_db2")
    cursor = con.cursor()

    cursor.execute("UPDATE valuedb SET all_value=?", (textbox1.get(), textbox2.get(),))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Saved and Update')


#SAVE BUTTON
save = tk.Button(root, text="Save & Update", bg='#b40909', foreground='white', command= save)
save.place(x=1, y=70)

#load()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You ask how to improve your code. Why do you think it needs improving? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @BryanOakley You are right, sorry. I edited the question. However the problem is that the textbox values are not saved to the database when the button is clicked. I think there is a problem in the save function

Comment: You didn't provide values to the SQL statement, so what do you expect?

Comment: @acw1668 could you show me how I can? So new to Python, sorry for the trivial errors. I'm learning. Your help will be precious to me for teaching purposes. Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what `textbox1` and `textbox2` represent. Which one is for `id`? Which one is for `all_value`?

Comment: Your updated code should get error because there is only one placeholder in the SQL statement but two values are supplied.  Also the SQL statement will update all records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the queries but not passing in the parameters required for it

```py
#Save
def save():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("/home/Qi_Yao/Desktop/my_db.db")
    c = conn.cursor()

    if c:
        c.execute("UPDATE valuedb SET all_value=? WHERE id=?;", (textbox1.get(), textbox2.get()))
    else:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO valuedb VALUES (?);", (textbox1.get(),)) # Should be (?, ?) because the table has two fields as seen in the update query?
  
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    messagebox.showinfo('Success', 'Saved and Update')
```

This should fix the problem of the items not saving to the database, but you should probably check your logic on what you expect to happen with `if c:`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, my little careless mistake, there should be two fields in INSERT. What's wrong with c's logic? I would simply like to update a textbox, or if it is empty, insert the values (and then always update it the following times). Can you explain better what's wrong with c's logic and show me an example to help please? Thank you

Comment: @Qi_Yao I wouldnt mind but a post should generally only consist one question, its better to ask a new question. "How can I fix my code" is not a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: My question was about the upload issue. You only added parameters to my code, but I didn't solve anything (I didn't solve even a single question). Adding parameters to my code, why should that be a solution? Why should I accept your answer if I haven't solved anything? (it's not an argument, but I'm calmly trying to understand) :) I would have liked a slightly more complete answer, then as you said, it would have been appropriate to open another question, but I think your answer should have at least fixed something to a small extent. Thank you

Comment: @Qi_Yao Quoting you: _"The problem is that the textbox values are not saved to the database when the button is clicked."_. This fixes that. How does adding parameters fix the problem? Without the parameters how does the connector know which value to insert

Comment: Yes, but if I try to use the code in my question (with the addition of your solution) and enter the values and then click the button, the values are not saved.

Comment: @Qi_Yao How do you verify that?

Comment: When you enter something into the textboxes and then click the button, you get an error: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: valuedb. Maybe there is something wrong with Sql, I'm confused. The file is called my_db. the table is called valuedb. the field is called all_value

Comment: @Qi_Yao How are you verifying that? Do you have a database browser?

Comment: DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: If you are connecting to the right database, and the code is also same then this problem should not occur.

Comment: I knew this too

Comment: Please dont update your question with the answers your received from the post. You should note that the new code with the table creation is DIFFERENT from the initial code. You only have one column in the new code but you are inserting into two column

Comment: Now I'll improve and update the question, so I can make it more clear. I hope you will help me, because your current answer doesn't help me. Thank you

Comment: Fix and improved question. Now I ask only one thing. Before I asked for INSERT and UPLOAD, now I only ask for Upload. I hope you can help me. Thanks and sorry

Comment: What error do  you get now?

Comment: Always about the same previous error. If I click on the button,the save/update seems to have been successful,but if I open the database then the values (previously entered manually) are not updated. The problem therefore is that the value I write in the textboxes does not update the database fields. Obviously the update must be multiple (it must update if I modify all the textboxes or even just one). I've simplified the problem a lot and simplified the code too. Now the code and help are intuitive. I await your kind solution. I will be happy to accept your solution. Thank you

Comment: @Qi_Yao You can update the question with your progress, independent from the ones received on the answer